# React Native: How combine Two colors for view background

Tags: react-native

I want a react native view style with two color gradient combine like the picture bellow :
[image: colorPicExample]

NOTE: I dont want use LinearGradient and etc. repository

Comment: Have a look at this article: https://medium.com/react-native-training/react-native-bridging-how-to-make-linear-gradient-view-83c3805373b7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [react-native-linear-gradient](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-linear-gradient) would solve your problem.
just  install it on the npm and use it like this example:

```
    <LinearGradient start={{x: 0, y: 0}} end={{x: 1, y: 0}} colors={['#4c669f', '#3b5998', '#192f6a']} style={styles.linearGradient}>

  <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
    Sign in with Facebook
  </Text>

</LinearGradient>
```

you can do more by reading [this](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-linear-gradient) reference

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23241170)

Comment: this component is part of main components which react native introduced in react-native-community. however i  tried to make it better in edit.  @Rob

Comment: It doesn't matter. Link only answers are not allowed on SO under any circumstances.